# Same code, Same SDK, Same LIBSDL version, Same GCC version with different results (PPC vs Intel)

Tags: macos, cocoa, sdl, 32bit-64bit

I have compiled BlueMSX for a Powerbook G4 using Leopard just fine using 10.5 and 10.4 SDKs. Then, I took the same source code and makefile and tried the same on an Intel Mac running Lion. Only adjusted the makefile to point to the new SDK and everything went fine again. But, when running the emulator all colors were completely wrong and also sound was corrupted.

My only suspicious is that there might be a difference with some data type sizes from 32 to 64 bits on SDL. Is there something like that?

Comment: Someone knows if it's possible to choose 64 or 32 bit SDL during compilation?